# How to create default local variables out of a called method in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Let's assume I have a method with several parameters:

```
void myMethod(String param, Integer count, Boolean fun, Object object) {
    ...
}
```

Now I call my method

```
myMethod(param, count, fun, object);
```

and it is clear that I need to initialize my local variables which basically don't exist yet. Let's assume that i want to do some preprocessing for each of this variables, thus I need each of them extracted as a local variable.

**Question:** *how to create local variables with correct types and even default values with one click/shortcut?*

**Possible solution:** For now I found only the possibility to come with the cursor to each of the variables and create a local out of it, but if I have a method with more parameters it gives more troubles.

Comment: I use Alt+Enter which will go through all the error on the screen, no need to move the cursor.

Comment: may I just ask, why you need that kind of a reverse procedure? Is there more primary problem? :))

Comment: @PeterLawrey, interesting, but I haven't noticed this working for me.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne just out of curiosity.

Comment: @VladimirTikhomirov curiosity is nice. anyway when we develop software, people ONLY care about POSSIBLE use cases. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible right now.

I understand your issue, but honestly it is not something that happens a lot to me: Usually some/many of the parameters are already available as variables in the scope. So it does not bother me much to do Alt-Enter a couple of times.

Also I think it would be confusing for me to deal with multiple introduced variables at the same time. I like to sequential workflow which lets me think about one parameter at a time.

You can always create a feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Answer (score 0):

For default params, you can override the method and call that method with default param with it.For example, your method declare like this:

```
public void myMethod(String param, Integer count, Boolean fun, Object object) {
    System.out.println(String.format("1:%s, 2:%d, 3:%s, 4:%s", param, count, fun, object));
}
```

and you want the second and fourth parameter left default, you can override the method like this:

```
public void myMethod(String param, Boolean fun) {
    myMethod(param, 0, fun, null);
}
```

and they are called like this:

```
myMethod("abc", 123, true, "xyz");
myMethod("abc", true);
```

here is the result:

```
1:abc, 2:123, 3:true, 4:xyz
1:abc, 2:0, 3:true, 4:null
```

Comment: It seems that you didn't get my question. The point what I ask is that I want to create local variables with one action in Intellij IDEA based on the method call where local variables are not defined and initialize which means that they will be highlighted. So, question is more about IDE than about the language.